# After IV regression, what does it mean if my endogenous variable is non-significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, panel-data, instrumental-variables

I have a possible endogenous variable $x_{k}$ (banks liquid assets ratio) in my regression equation of $y$ (banks overdraft ratio of total loans) from a long panel-data.

I have two "good" instruments $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$ (monetary policy variables) for my endogenous variable (they are non-significant in the main regression and theoretically they should not be; they are highly correlated with the endogenous variable).

I did an IV regression (or 2SLS) with my two instruments $z_{1,2}$.

I found no statistical significance of the endogenous variable $x_{k}$ in the second-stage regression.

What does it mean? (the endogenous $x_{k}$ is significant when I did panel regression estimations (PCSE, OLS with AR(1) model, etc).

Theory does not provide a clear answer if this $x_{k}$ should or not be significant.

Comment: 2SLS estimates will be less precise than OLS. It sounds like you cannot reject the null hypothesis that $x_k$ has no effect on $y$.

Comment: An insignificant result is also a result.